Are distributions over the simplex always a mixture of Dirichlet?
For any random variables $P=(P_1,\ldots,P_k)$ over the simplex, is the distribution of $P$ always a finite mixture of Dirichlet distributions, i.e., $\mathrm{Dir}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$ for $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ drawn according to some distribution over a finite set? If not can it be written as an infinite mixture? What if $k=2$ (i.e., beta random variables)?
If $(P_1,\ldots,P_k)$ remains identically distributed under any permutation of indices, can its distribution always be written as mixture of $\mathrm{Dir}(\alpha,\ldots,\alpha)$ (the hyperparameters are all the same)?

The $1$-simplex is just a line, and you can pick an arbitrary distribution over a line that isn't related to the Dirichlet distributions, e.g. the semicircular distribution or something.

Of course not. For your second question for instance, suppose that your distribution on $(0,1)$ has a strictly positive density $f$ (an obvious necessary condition). You are wondering if there exists a  probability measure $\mu(dt)$ on $(0,\infty)$ such that
$$f(x)=f(1-x)=\int_0^{\infty}(x(1-x))^t\frac{\mu(dt)}{B(t,t)}.$$ For seeing that it is not always possible, define $y$ by $e^{y}=x(1-x)$ for $0<x<1/2$ (say), or $x(y)=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{1-4e^y})$ with $-\infty <y<-\log 4$ and denote $$g(y)=f(x(y))=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ty}\frac{\mu(dt)}{B(t,t)}.$$ In other terms, $g$ is the Laplace transform of the positive measure $\mu_1(dt)=\frac{\mu(dt)}{B(t,t)}.$ This means that $g$ has a very special form, for instance $\log g$ should be convex and real analytic: no reason for $f$ to fullfill these conditions. Quite analogous reasoning can be applied in the general cases, giving necessary and sufficient conditions in terms of Laplace transform in the Dirichlet case.
